# Android Studio Adding External Library (android-maven error)

Tags: java, android, maven, gradle, android-studio

I've fairly new to android studio. I've been trying to add an external library (Crouton) to my project but when i try to sync, i keep getting this error

Error:(30, 0) Plugin with id 'android-maven' not found.

This is the build.gradle for the Crouton library

```
 buildscript {
 repositories {
     mavenCentral()
 }
 dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.+'
 }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'android-maven'
apply plugin: 'signing'
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean the [keyboardsurfer/Crouton](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton) project, you can import the project by including

```
dependencies {
    compile 'de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.5'
}
```

in your `build.gradle` as per [gradleplease.appspot.com](http://gradleplease.appspot.com/#crouton) (which makes it easy to figure out how to include projects in your Android Studio projects) - you shouldn't have to import anything or worry about how their build.gradle is set up.

Comment: Thanks so much! Although i was still getting this error `Module version de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.5 depends on libraries but is not a library itself`.
Just had to add `exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'` to fix it :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and it was solved by adding the following in build.gradle file under dependencies:

```
compile ('de.keyboardsurfer.android.widget:crouton:1.8.5') {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```